# Set Subtitle of Toolbar with JetPack Navigation Architecture Components

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using the JetPack Navigation Architecture Components and I can set the title of the Toolbar in my Navigation Graph with `android:label="@string/event_lists_toolbar_title"`. I would also like to set the subtitle, but cannot find a way to do so, except via code in my Fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.subtitle = getString(R.string.my_subtitle)

        // ...
}
```

But the subtitle then stays and I have to reset it after I navigate again to another Screen. I could do this in the `onPause()` function or like this in my Activity (NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener):

```
override fun onDestinationChanged(controller: NavController, destination: NavDestination, arguments: Bundle?) {

        // resets subtitle of Toolbar
        if (destination.id != R.id.fragment_with_subtitle) {
            supportActionBar?.subtitle = ""
        }
}
```

Isn't there a better solution for this? Doesn't support Navigation that out of the box?

Comment: Have you solved it? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Hi, no I couldn't find a better solution than just resetting the subtitle in `onDestinationChanged` in my Activity.